# Maintain Selection of QComboBox under a QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

Below is an example of a custom delegated `QComboBox`. When I make a selection, click out (or otherwise lose focus with the `QComboBox`), and then TAB back in (gain focus), I lose my original selection.  For example, using the below code if I choose `"Item 2"`, click out, then TAB back in, the selection will go back to `"Item 1."`

**How can I maintain the selection?**

I am assuming this issue occurs because I am using `addItem()` in `TheEditor` `QComboBox` class every time it is initialized except I am not too sure how I should be approaching this method. Should I instead be initalizing `TheEditor` in the `EditDelegate` `__ init __` class so that it is only initialized once and not every time it is focused? How might I do that properly?

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql

class EditDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(EditDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
            editor = TheEditor(parent)                  
            return editor

class TheEditor(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(TheEditor, self).__init__(parent)
            self.addItem("Item 1")
            self.addItem("Item 2")
            self.addItem("Item 3")
            self.setEditable(True)

class TheTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, columns, parent=None):
            super(TheTable, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setItemDelegate(EditDelegate())
            self.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.AllEditTriggers)
            self.setColumnCount(1)
            self.setRowCount(1)
            self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["QCombo"])

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
            self.setCentralWidget(TheTable(self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    frame = MainWindow()
    frame.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Note: PySide v1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

As QT Introduction to ([Model/View Programming](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/model-view-programming.html)) says

> Note that we do not need to keep a pointer to the editor widget because the view takes responsibility for destroying it when it is no longer needed.

editor is temporary object. But you can try catching selection from old editor and pass it to new editor like this:

```
class EditDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    editorsLastIndex=None
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(EditDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = TheEditor(parent)             
        if self.editorsLastIndex != None:
            editor.setCurrentIndex(self.editorsLastIndex)
        editor.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.editorIndexChanged)
        return editor
    def editorIndexChanged(self, index):
        self.editorsLastIndex = index
```